# The zsh command returns an error when I use a variable in the parameters

Tags: zsh

I'm running a zsh script `./signFiles`.

I have the following error when I introduce the **$runtime** variable in the `codesign` command :

> codesign: unrecognized option `--options runtime'

```
#!/bin/zsh

[…]

runtime="--options runtime"
codesign --timestamp --force $runtime --prefix="$identifier." -s "$ID_Application_signature" $file
```

Everything works fine when I hardcode the `--options runtime` in the command :

```
codesign --timestamp --force --options runtime --prefix="$identifier." -s "$ID_Application_signature" $file
```

Doesn't seems so hard to be resolved but I just can't make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**RESOLVED**
Thanks to the comment of @chepner :

```
runtime=(--options runtime)
codesign --timestamp --force "${runtime[@]}" ...
```

Comment: The error implies you are using `zsh`, in which case word-splitting is not applied to the unquoted parameter expansion. I would expect this to work (fragile though it is) in `bash`. In either shell, you should use an array instead: `runtime=(--options runtime)` and `codesign --timestamp --force "${runtime[@]}" ...`.

Comment: The error should not occur in Bash with default settings.  One possibility is that earlier in the code [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) has been disabled by setting `IFS` to the empty string (e.g. `IFS=`).  Another possibility is that the code is being run with Zsh instead of Bash.

Comment: Are you doing this interactively or is it in a script? If it's a script, how are you running the script? Does it have a shebang line?

Comment: Just to spell this out, Bash and Zsh are two different shells. Using the [tag:bash] tag when asking about [tag:zsh] is just confused, and confusing.

Comment: True, I modified it. Sorry for the inconveniance

Comment: Why are you mentioning bash if you don't use bash? As for zsh: If you write `--options runtime`, codesign sees two arguments here (`--options` and `runtime`). If you write `$runtime`, codesign sees one argument (`--options runtime`). If you had written `${(z)runtime}`, codesplit would have seen two argument.

Comment: I modified bash by zsh but the modification has not yet been taken into consideration. Chepner's comment has solved my issue. Thanks for your help